# How to put a file open dialog in Xcode UI builder?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I found the code which reading from a file, and take a path from dialog on official docs Microsoft. But didn't find a way how to put this window in Xcode.

Here's [a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/user-interface/dialog#the-open-dialog)

Comment: The Cocoa Open and Save panels do not exist as UI design time controls, you have to instance them via code.

Comment: @SushiHangover okay, in the example I got an error about MainWindowController. I thought it passed when Xcode synchronizing with VS. Then I don't know how to define this class or where I can import him.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/mac-samples/tree/master/MacWindows